# How can I uniquely ID the AWS Lambda container that my function is running in?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I would like to get the (AWS Lambda container) instance ID that my function is running in.

For now I would just log it - it would help me when debugging issues with my caching algorithm: I could identify which invocations were happening in the same instance.

I looked at [the docs for the context object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html) and don't see anything there.

I could do it manually - and I'll put that below as my fallback answer - but I thought I would check whether some sort of real instance ID is available somehow.

Comment: As I wrote this it started to come to me - my Q is silly in a way.  What is important really isn't instance re-use but data/name space re-use so my fallback answer - which depends on global being re-used - is actually better then getting the actual container instance ID.  Never-the-less, if someone knows how to get the instance ID I will mark it as the correct answer (since technically it will be).

Answer (score 11):

Could just generate a random GUID save that in global.  (I'm just starting to look at this issue of container re-use and the potential for data caching, but I assume that node's 'global' object remains intact when an instance is re-used.)